# Dictionary of types and actions with a generic parameter

Tags: c#, generics, delegates, action

I am trying to get a simple messaging service going using MessagePack.

The service should keep a `dictionary<type, Action<T>>` in order to look up how to "deal" with a particular message.

Basically, I have:

```
    private Dictionary<Type, Action<IMessage>> subActions;

    public void Subscribe<TMessage>(Action<TMessage> action) where TMessage : IMessage
    {
        subActions.Add(typeof(TMessage), action);
    }
```

I get:

```
Argument 2: cannot convert from 'System.Action<TMessage>' to 'System.Action<GameServer.Messages.IMessage>'
```

In case it's not clear; The messages "arrive" as a `byte[]` containing a "typecode". From the "typecode" I get the `Type`, and *should* then be able to look up the appropriate `Action` to take. The `Action` should, obviously, take the `TMessage` as a parameter.

I can't seem to come to a logical conclusion as to why the compiler is giving me this error although I suspect it has something to do with the `Dictionary` not being in the same context as `TMessage`.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you are trying to accomplish here, but the restriction of `TMessage` to be `IMessage` feels wrong.

Comment: @P.Brian.Mackey TBH i'd rather not use IMessage at all. I just couldn't think of any other way than using `private Dictionary<Type, Action<Object>> subActions;` and I'd rather avoid having to cast the `Object` to the `Tmessage`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's consider these methods:

```
public void MessageMethodInterface(IMessage arg)
{

}
public void MessageMethodClass(MyMessage arg)
{

}
```

Where `MyMessage` is a class that implements the `IMessage` interface.

Let's now create an `Action` and use them:

```
var action = new Action<IMessage>(MessageMethodInterface);
action(new SomeOtherMessage());
```

`SomeOtherMessage` implements `IMessage`. This will work. We have an `Action` that takes `IMessage` as an input. Since SomeOtherMessage implements IMessage it compiles and works.

Let's now create another `Action`:

```
var action2 = new Action<IMessage>(MessageMethodClass);
action(new SomeOtherMessage());
```

This will not work: We created an `Action` that should take any object of type `IMessage` but we assigning to it a method that is only able to handle input of type `MyMessage` class - hence we narrowing the scope of the action with the method we provided - it won't compile.

What happens in your code is the scenario 2. You want your dictionary to hold methods that can handle `IMessage` but you are passing in methods that can handle only specific type. This is not type safe. Even if a class implements the interface, the method itself is only handling the specific type, not every type of that interface. Same as in the example with `MyMessage` and `SomeOtherMessage`.

It's the contravariance of the `Action` type.
An `Action` of a base type can have assigned an action of a derived type. This is type safe b/c the method that only uses base type will know how to handle the derived type. The opposite is not true. Method taking `object` as input will handle `string`. Since `string` exposes all the methods and properties of the `object`. But not the other way around.

More on [contravariance of Action type is here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/generics/covariance-and-contravariance).

Comment: I see, it makes sense. The reason I tried this way was to avoid having to cast the `IMessage` to the *actual* desired message type. I know it's not a big deal to add `(ActualMessageType) message` in each of the `Action`s, but is there any easy way to avoid casting?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand the solution with casting. Even if you force the action to take your method b/c you've cast it to expected type, when executing your handler will be accepting IMessage input since that's the signature in the dictionary. I cannot think of a clean, generic solution to your problem... But the reason for what you see is as in the answer. Contravariance sounds bit counter intuitive at first but when you analyse it it actually prevents type unsafe behaviours.

Comment: Ok. I'll have to past another question I think... Does this wording make sense: How to implement a collection of type constrained generic Actions (Action<T> where T : Type)?

Comment: I don't have a neat solution. Perhaps a collection based on `object`: `Dictionary<Type, Action<object>> subActions`. And then the `Subscribe` method that takes `object`. Something like this `public void Subscribe<T>(Action<object> action)`. But it's far from ideal solution.

Answer (score 0):

It is not working, because you want to make assigning like:

```
Action<IMessage> dest = new Action<TMessage>(x => x.TMessageProp = 123);
```

so, if it will be allowed by compiler, further you will can, for example, to write:

```
dest(new TAnotherMessage());
```

because `TAnotherMessage` also implements `IMessage`. But it will cause exception, because `dest` can works only with `TMessage`. Read more about  contravariance.

You can remain type safety and [fix it safely](https://dotnetfiddle.net/vaGvVg), because nevertheless you know types, which you can pass to particular action via dictionary's key:

```
public void Subscribe<TMessage>(Action<TMessage> action) where TMessage : IMessage
{
    subActions.Add(typeof(TMessage), x => action((TMessage)x));
}
```